# Swift: intermittent, inconsistent, unexpected behavior using Set.insert()

Tags: swift, set

**Edit:** I never thought to restart Xcode after deleting the derived data. Now everything works exactly as expected.

I'm running into intermittent failures in my app. I've narrowed it down to some strangeness with `Set.insert()`. Sometimes the insert results in a call to my `==` function, other times not, for no apparent reason. Here's the best stripped-down sample I can come up with; it runs in playground.

```
// Results are the same whether I use Equatable or not
struct ID: Hashable, Equatable {
    let idNumber: Int

    // Results are the same whether I implement this or not
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(idNumber)
    }

    // Always return true; it doesn't matter. What matters
    // is that sometimes the Set.insert() doesn't even
    // call this function.
    static func == (_ lhs: ID, _ rhs: ID) -> Bool {
        print("(eq)", terminator: ""); return true
    }
}

let id0 = ID(idNumber: 0)
let id1 = ID(idNumber: 1)

var uniqueIDs = Set<ID>()

print("a", terminator: "")
uniqueIDs.insert(id0)
print("b", terminator: "")
uniqueIDs.insert(id1)
print("c", terminator: "")
```

If I run this ten times in the playground, about half the time I'll see `eq` in the output, and half the time not. That is, about half the time `Set.insert()` doesn't call my `==` before trying the insert.

I read up on Swift sets, and didn't find anything that would shed any light. I sort of thought that if this were the intended behavior, it would be documented with a big warning sign attached. The lack of such warnings suggests that I'm misusing `Sets`, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What doc, or which SO answer, have I missed?

Comment: You probably will be suprised, that your code does not print "eq" when run on blank application instead of playground.
My suggestion is, that, it does not call "==" for some reason, or, implementation is hidden from us. Maybe you should end up rewriting default Set for suite your needs?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban The point is not that it fails to call `==`, the point is that `Set` is giving me inconsistent behavior using the same input data. I'm not trying to do anything custom with `Set`. My understanding is that `insert()` will not insert the same element twice, but it is indeed inserting the same element twice, in conjunction with failing to call `==`. The failure to call `==` is a clue, not the problem I'm trying to address.

Answer (score 2):

`Set` has no reason to call `==` on your type if there are not value collisions. I  this is a red herring.

`Set` calls `hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` on your values, and then takes the modulo of the set's internal array size. The result is an index at which the value (if it already exists in the set) should be. Naturally, this process makes it possible for multiple values, after hashing and taking modulo, to end up in the same array slot.

To compensate for this, rather than the elements being stored directly in the array slots, they're stored by a linked list. Conceptually, the items within the same slot are called a "bucket". When looking up an element `Set` uses the hash value to find the right bucket, but needs to iterate through the linked list to find the exact element. At this point, hashes are no longer useful for identitying elements, so `Set` uses `==` checks until it finds the right match. This is usually pretty efficient, because the `Set` should be making the array large enough that buckets are small and contain very few collisions.

Because finding an element within a bucket is `O(N)`, if you can force many hash collisions, then you can force `Set`'s `O(1)` insert/remove/check operations to degenerate into `O(N)` traversals over the entire `Set`'s elements (since you could make all elements map to a single bucket. To counter DOS vulnerability, modern associative data structures uses a "seed" that is randomly chosen every time the app is run, and use that to scramble the hashes. This way, it becomes very difficult to craft payloads with identical hash values (which would cause the over-sized bucket issue.) That's where your non-determinism is coming from. See [PSA: The stdlib now uses randomly seeded hash values](https://forums.swift.org/t/psa-the-stdlib-now-uses-randomly-seeded-hash-values/10789?u=alexanderm).

Fundamentally, `Set<T>` is really just a `Dictionary` of type `[T: Void]`. So if you read into how hash-based associative data structures (other common names are  as Dictionaries, Hashes, HashMaps, etc.) work, much of the same applies.

Comment: Thank you. So the fact that it was calling `==` at all was strange, I didn't realize that. But it wasn't the call to `==` that mattered. My problem was that 50% of the time, it would call `==`, and the other 50%, it wouldn't call. Weirdest DerivedData bug I've ever seen. Thanks for teaching me about the internals of sets!

Comment: @GreatBigBore Well having `==` isn't a problem. In an ideal world, your hash keys would be uniformly distributed, even in such a way that they stay unique after the modulo operation. But in practice, there will almost always be some collisions, and that's okay. "was that 50% of the time, it would call ==, and the other 50%, it wouldn't call." -> Because of the randomized hash seed. Some values of it will cause collisions (thus requiring set to call `==`), some values of it won't. That's to be expected, once you know about these internals :)

Answer (score 0):

Look like playground somehow broken. That's because, the same code i past in blank app project have different output that the same code in playground. Please take a look:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        doSmth()
        return true
    }

    func doSmth(){


        // Results are the same whether I use Equatable or not
        struct ID: Hashable, Equatable {
            let idNumber: Int

            // Results are the same whether I implement this or not
            func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
                hasher.combine(idNumber)
            }

            // Always return true; it doesn't matter. What matters
            // is that sometimes the Set.insert() doesn't even
            // call this function.
            static func == (_ lhs: ID, _ rhs: ID) -> Bool {
                // print("(eq)", terminator: "");
                // return false
                return true
            }
        }

        let id0 = ID(idNumber: 0)
        let id1 = ID(idNumber: 1)
        let id2 = ID(idNumber: 2)

        var uniqueIDs = Set<ID>([id0, id1])

        uniqueIDs.insert(id0)
        uniqueIDs.insert(id1)
        uniqueIDs.insert(id2)
        uniqueIDs.insert(id0)
        uniqueIDs.insert(id1)

        uniqueIDs.forEach{ value in
            print("value - \(value)")
        } 
    }
}
```

It prints out:

```
value - ID(idNumber: 0)
value - ID(idNumber: 1)
value - ID(idNumber: 2)
```

No duplicates (even when i tried to add duplicates).

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: @GreatBigBore your code is working as expected and print correct values. I have no idea why playground print wrong values.

Comment: "I have no idea" is not an answer. Also, I mentioned in my question that I'm having trouble with my app, not with playgrounds. I used playgrounds to demonstrate the problem. Never mind. I deleted DerivedData and restarted Xcode, and the problem went away.

Comment: I could not look up in your app and code your provided is ok. And of course i have no idea of inner implementation of iOS SDK.